# document.getElementsByTagName("a") misses a link

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Edit: it's been ages since I've ran into this "issue" back then, and by now it's even simpler

```
for (const link of links) { }
```

I was working on a script for Greasemonkey (FX7) trying to remove certain links and found out that for some reason one that was present in the source, not hidden or constructed by JS, didn't show up in the array that that function returns.

If that one would have been constructed via JS upon running that page it wouldn't wonder me but it's sitting right behind another link that gets found.

So has anyone an idea why this is happening and how I could work around it?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var l in links){
  if (links[l].href == "blah"){ ... }
}
```

Thats how I was trying to work with them, a bit cut down as I had some more checks to not run into nulls and such.

On a sidenote: I was wondering why that function also returns null entries at all.

Edit: I passed this problem long since I asked for help and found a nice way to do it:

```
for (var i = 0, l; l = links[i]; i++) { }
```

This keeps setting l to the current link until there aren't any left. Works nice.

Comment: Documents have a [links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection that is all the links in the document. Consider using that instead of `getElementsByTagName('a')` since A elements aren't necessarily links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The for...in statement loops through the properties of an object. In this particular case you are iterating over Array object properties. Try to use this script instead:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
  if (links[l].href == "blah"){ ... }
}
```

Comment: If the `...` includes removing the link, make sure to have `l--` after that part, otherwise the one after will be skipped due to the NodeList being live. Alternatively, start from the end with `for( var l=link.length-1; l>=0; l--)`

Comment: @Kolink, thanks for remark. +1 if you'll post this as answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. About the "for in", it's normally like a normal forward for loop like Yuriy posted but that index stepback was missing and I totally failed to notice that. Weirdly "l--;" upon removing a link worked with "for in" for all except the last one. Anyways I now did the reverse one and it's working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`for … in` statements loop through the *properties* of an object, not only its values, just like @Yuriy said. You'll need to learn some Javascript to understand this (sorry, couldn't find any direct pointer to this part after a few minutes of Googling).

Basically, you need to understand that objects in JS also include “methods”. When you're using a `for … in` loop, you find an object's values but also its “methods” and other properties.

So, either use @Yuriy's indexed loop… or better, use the `hasOwnProperty()` method ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)), that allows to avoid the very important caveat @Kolink mentioned.

Your loop should look like:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var l in links) {
    if (! links.hasOwnProperty(l))
        continue; // this goes straight to the next property

    if (links[l].href == "blah") { ... }
}
```

Comment: Actually, using `for`... `in` syntax is verboten in Greasemonkey due to the XPCNativeWrapper.

Comment: @BrockAdams Oh, interesting. But then how come the OP was able to use it, even without perfect results?!

Comment: Just because it doesn't work as expected, nor should it be used if you want GM scripts that work, versus SO questions, does not mean that it does not *appear* to work to some less rigorous eyes.  Read the GM pitfalls.

Comment: I just use "for var l in list" because it seems to work like "for var l=0; l < list.length; l++" with just less to write. Never noticed any problems with it unless this time, funny is though that "l--;" worked upon removing but only for all except the last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
     if (links[i].href.match('blah')){...}
  };
```

Comment: Hi Victoria, I know this is your first time posting an answer! If you would explain what you did differently or how you improved it, it helps immensely, not just for the original poster, but for anyone else coming across this question.

Comment: I used the match() method that looks for specific string and returns it as an array

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByTagName ("area") [0] returns the value of its href attribute and not HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: the same happens with getElementsByTagName ("a") [0]

Comment: Error: 
getElementsByTagName ("area") [0] returns the value of its href attribute and not HTMLAreaElement
shareeditdeleteflag